# How to find usages of a PHP method with variable number of arguments, grouping by number of arguments passed?

Tags: php, ide

I have inherited a PHP method that takes 18 arguments, 16 optionally; I would like to refactor it.

How can I find usages of this method, grouping by the number of arguments passed?

Is there a way in IntelliJ (or any other IDE) to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With Zend Studio, just right-click on the name of the method and select "Open Call Hierarchy".

I guess that you can find similar functions in other IDE's :)

Comment: Does this group by number of arguments passed?

Comment: I've been checking it and, sadly no. But just clicking on the line you can directly go to the exact file and line and check it yourself. Does it work for you? Should I remove the answer?

Comment: " Does it work for you?" I'm not OP, but OP specifically asked for it in his question though. So whether this is useful only OP can decide :)

Comment: I can already find usages in IntelliJ and check each one individually. Unfortunately, there are more than 400 calls, so it's a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Netbeans if your methods are correctly commented

Comment: Does this group by number of arguments passed?

Comment: I think no by arguments but you can sort by name and maybe by longer

Read the code convention for commented method : https://netbeans.org/community/guidelines/code-conventions.html